# replace underscores with hyphens on one parameter only and then 301 in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to replace underscores with hyphens only on a particular parameter and then perform a 301 redirect.  I have figured out how to replace them and apply it to the entire URL but cannot figure out how to replace them for just one paramater.  Right now I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([a-zA-Z_]+)&city=([a-zA-Z_]+)$
RewriteRule city.html /find/this/in/%2/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

This 301 redirects this:
mysite.com/city.html?state=va&city=dunn_loring

To this:
mysite.com/find/this/in/dunn_loring/va/

I would like it to instead 301 redirect to this:
mysite.com/find/this/in/dunn-loring/va/

Essentially I only want to replace underscores with hyphens for the '%1' portion in my htaccess example above.  Thanks in advance for any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution works with no limit on the number on underscores. The first RewriteRule replaces the first underscore seen and the [N] flag causes processing to start over, so the rule will keep being applied until all the underscores are replaced. When no more underscores are left, the redirect is issued.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([a-zA-Z_]+)&city=([a-zA-Z-]+)_([a-zA-Z_-]+)$
RewriteRule city.html /city.html?state=%1&city=%2-%3 [N]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([a-zA-Z_]+)&city=([a-zA-Z-]+)$
RewriteRule city.html /find/this/in/%2/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you so much!  this answer is perfect and well explained.  I appreciate it